# cocoa : how to use nstimeinterval property as a global variable

Tags: cocoa

I have declared NSTimeInterval as a property in a singleton class and i want to use it in another class with the value retained.

```
NSTimeInterval startTime=[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
```

I want to use this start time in another class

Example : i can create a property of type NSDate 
like @property(assign)NSDate *startDate;
and make it global by writing code in init method

self.startTime=[[NSDate alloc]]init;
but , how can i do this in case of nstimeinterval

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

`NSTimeInterval` is not an object so doesn't need to be retained.

From the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html):

> `NSTimeInterval` Used to specify a time interval, in seconds.
>
> `typedef double NSTimeInterval;`
>
> NSTimeInterval is always specified in seconds; it yields sub-millisecond precision over a range
> of 10,000 years.